# LINQ Get Results of object contained in another List by more than one Value

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have two lists one of Class Kids that has all the honor kids and one that has all the Students and thier classroom, let's say that I want to get all the students and their classroom that are in the Honors list:

```
public class Kids 
{
    string FirstName;
    string LastName;
    int Age;
    int Grade; 
}

public class Students
{
    string FirstName;
    string LastName;
    string Classroom; 
}
```

I was thinking of using something like this query:

```
List<Students> students = classroom
         .Where(i => honorKids
                    .Select(j => j.FirstName)
                    .Contains(i.FirstName) && honorKids
                           .Select(j => j.LastName)
                           .Contains(i.LastName)
               )
```

the problem is that there is no correlation of the First Name and last name of the kid so for example if there is is an honor student named John Bezoz and another honor student Mark Smith and a non-honor student named John Smith it will return as an honor student since both his first name and lastname are in the honor list but not in the same row.

how could I make the comparison to make sure first name and last name are in the list but in the same row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to perform `Select`'s, try using [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_Any__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) with corresponding predicate instead:

```
List<Students> students = classroom
    .Where(i => honorKids.Any(j => j.FirstName == i.FirstName && j.LastName == i.LastName))
    .ToList();
```